# Не приходит @AuthenticationPrincipal Jwt principal

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

В общем контроллер, в котором отлавливаю principal, но почему - то приходит null

```
@GetMapping("/user/info")
    public void getUserInfo(@AuthenticationPrincipal Jwt principal) {
        String userId = principal.getClaimAsString("user_id");

    }
```

В application.yaml:

```
security:
  oauth2:
    authorization:
      jwt:
        key-store: classpath:jwt/jwt.jks
        key-alias: jwt
        key-store-password: storePassword
```

Вот так я отправляю запрос с токеном:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ДЕКОДЕР СВОЙ НЕ ПИСАЛ, ПОТОМУ ЧТО ТРЕБУЕТ jwk-set-uri

Comment: Тут многое зависит от настроек Spring Security. Само оно не будет работать. Я для Jwt реализовывал свой AuthenticationProvider, который мне собственно формировал правильный Authentication, который прекрасно инжектится в параметры контроллеров без всяких аннотаций.

Comment: @zolt я по другому сделал, переопределял конвертер токена и сделал так как мне нужно)